# JQuery UI: Change slider max inside of event handler

Tags: jquery-ui, events, slider

I am a little bit stuck:

I would like to change the "max" option of a JQueryUI slider while I am inside an event (e.g. `change:`).

How do I call the "max" option when I am inside an event?

**EDIT:** My code looks as follows:

```
$('#slider0').slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        range: "min",
        step: 50,
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            var amt_val = (THIS IS THE CURRENT VALUE OF THE SLIDER)
            if(amt_val === 400) {
                $('#slider0').slider("option", "max", 10);
            }
        }
});
```

However, whenever I set the slider equal to 400, the handle and value go to 0, and the handle freezes.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WKyYv/3/, however your selectors should be enclosed in quotes like `$('#slider0')`

Comment: Ah - realized that my new value was too small while the width of the slider remained the same. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the option like

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "max", 7 );
```

Check the option tab of doc page for [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-max)

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WKyYv/